# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, securing boot and encrypting data on HDD with TPM 2.0

Tags: boot, uefi, encryption, tpm

I want to give for a rent some PC with some software (kiosk software).
I want to not allow people who will rent this PC to read any data on its HDD.
But they will have physical access to this PC.
There will be asus motherboard will asus external TPM 2.0 module.
There will be two users in a system - root and kiosk, both with secret passwords.

The question is what is the best and modern way to secure the data (if someone will try to read data with live cd or with changing shell at boot)?
I studied this problem and have concluded I have to realize the following:

1. Turn on UEFI and Secure Boot in BIOS settings
2. Sign bootable system parts (this point needs clarification - what parts? grub list / or may be use of grub2 / initrd ... etc ....).
3. The further actions is to use dm-crypt / crypttab / LUKS to setup fully encrypted HDD based on TPM 2.0
4. Somehow install all certs to TPM 2.0

But still I can't figure out what is the best and easiest (for unattended post-setup of all system encryption via sh scripts) way to do it? Should I use all tools mensioned in 3 par. in the list, or a couple of them?

May be there is any step-by-step info with explanation of each command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... and you should password protect entering BIOS settings.

Comment: ... and you should passwordprotect the recovery mode in GRUB

Answer (score 0):

I made this script to automatically unlock through TPM2: https://github.com/archee565/Bytelocker

BTW, I believe Linux installers should have an option to set this up automatically.